# How to get test-instances from HP ALM using REST API using Java?

Tags: java, rest, testing, alm

I've successfully connected to HP ALM, but do not know how to get the test-instance data. This is what the url looks like:

https://hpalm.hostname.ca/qcbin/rest/domains/domain_name/projects/project_name/test-instances

Is there a way to append a query to the URL and get all the test-instances under this project?

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? The URL you wrote should do the do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'http' instead of 'https'

http://hpalm.hostname.ca/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain_name}/projects/{project_name}/test-instances

Answer (score 1):

If you know the test set folder name these are sequence to testset get details

**To get the Parent folder id**

```
http://{url}:{port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain_name}/projects/{project_name}/test-set-folders?query={name[nameOfParentFolder];parent-id[0]}&fields=id,name
```

**To get a test set folder id**

```
http://{url}:{port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain_name}/projects/{project_name}/test-set-folders?query={name[nameOfTestSetFolder];parent-id[parentFolderId]}&fields=id,name
```

**To get the test set id**

```
http://{url}:{port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain_name}/projects/{project_name}/test-sets?query={name[nameOfTestSet];test-set-folder.id[testSetFolderId]}&fields=id,name
```

**To get the testInstanceId/testcycle-id**  :

```
http://{url}:{port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain_name}/projects/{project_name}/test-instances?query={cycle-id[testSetId];test-id[testId]}&fields=id,name,test-config-id
```